# Is there such thing as too many questions?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

A few days ago I noticed a user that was suspended to "cool down" (can't recall the name of the user but I think it was until August next year).

After that day, given that it wasn't clear the reason of what "cool down" meant (at least not in that description), I started to wonder: can asking "lots" (maybe up to 10) of questions in a relatively short period of time (+/- 2 hours) be reason for "cool down"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask too many bad questions (if they get closed with lots of downvotes) the site software itself will stop you from asking questions for a while. That's out of the hands of the mods - we can neither make a question ban nor lift one.

If someone asks lots of questions and becomes somehow disruptive to the community by doing so, the mods could give them a manual suspension for a while.

If someone asks a lot of good questions, well that's usually a good thing!

However if someone is constantly asking a lot of questions, like multiple questions every single day, and if they're fairly short and simple, we might ask them to slow down and consider if they can look for answers themselves first, and only post the ones which they really can't find any solution to. And if someone is asking a lot of questions in quick succession they're probably not doing due diligence to look for duplicates first. That way we can encourage high quality interesting questions, which is more valuable than pure quantity of questions.

Comment: Ok so in a scenario where the problem isn't closed questions with too many downvotes then there's an initial contact from moderation to express there's this concern?

Comment: "And if someone is asking a lot of questions in quick succession they're probably not doing due diligence to look for duplicates first", I disagree with that though

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Maybe, if the mods think it's worthwhile. To be honest, I doubt most people could ask more than one or two good questions a day. Most weeks I don't even have one!